# Do a HTTPPost request with JSON Body, Android

Tags: android, json, post, http-post, getjson

I 'm pretty new to Android. So, I 'm struggling with a HttpPost in android with Json Data.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObjDasUser = new JSONObject();

    jsonObj.put("name", "Login");
    jsonObj.put("type", "request");
    jsonObj.put("UserCredential", jsonObjUserCredential );
    jsonObjUserCredential .put("username", id);
    jsonObjUserCredential .put("password", password);

// Create the POST object and add the parameters
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);

entity.setContentType("application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

How can I include the jsonObjUserCredential as a entity like:::

```
//StringEntity userCredential = new StringEntity(jsonObjUserCredential .toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);??????
```

What am doing wrong here?????

Please Help me....

Comment: means you want to post Json data to we server right? what is jsonObjUserCredential can u plz post more code

Comment: jsonObjUserCredential  has contained two Attributes(username and password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myJSON", MyJSONObject.toString()));

//Set the http request 
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
httpPost = new HttpPost(webServiceUrl + methodName);

httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//Variable to keep the http response
response = null;

//Set the parameters if exist
if(params != null && !params.isEmpty()){
    try {
        //Set the parameters in the request
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

//Execute the call
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

Try this code ..
Hope this fix ur problem..

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObjDasUser = new JSONObject();

jsonObj.put("name", "Login");
jsonObj.put("type", "request");
jsonObjUserCredential .put("username", id);
jsonObjUserCredential .put("password", password);
jsonObj.put("UserCredential", jsonObjUserCredential );

// Create the POST object and add the parameters

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Thanks for your code..
For more detail 
My Json looks like this...

{ "name":"Login"
 ,"type":"request"
 ,"UserCredential": { "id": "xxxxx",
               "password": "xxxx"
             }
 }

If I do the same way as you 've said..'d that be a good JsonBody to do the HttpPost?
Thanks Dude

Comment: Thanks Sandeep .... I can see that the same JsonPost did posted but with change of order thats mean like this:
{"UserCredential":{"password":"xxxxx","id":"xxxxx"},"type":"request","name":"Login"}

That shouldn't be a issue is in it?

Now I 've this issue....
default buffer size used in bufferedreader constructor it would be better tobe explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required

How ca I fix it in my HttpPost ??

Comment: How can I query the JSON string in ASP.Net MVC server.?

Comment: Don't you have to add the stringentity to the post request?